# Change text size of RecycleView items from Options Item Menu in Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm having a trouble about RecyclerView Adapter. Please help me.

I am building an application to read the text and in an Activity, I created 2 options Item Menu to increase and decrease text Size of items that have been assign by recycleAdapter.
But I can't make it work. Can anyone tell me solution for this, please?

Edit:

This is the code that assign data to RecyclerView:

```
recycleViewItemList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecylerViewItemList);
                recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(getContext(), ContentChapter, "truyenchu");
                recycleViewItemList.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);
                recycleViewItemList.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Here is Options Item Menu Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.txtIncreaseTextSize:

            return true;
        case R.id.txtDecreaseTextSize:

            return true;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

And now I want to when I click txtIncreaseTextSize Button on ActionBar then the TextView text size will raise by 1. But the TextView is defined in RecyclerAdapter and I can't interact with it.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @quicklearner i just edit my post, is that enough? pls tell me if you need anything else. Thank you!

Comment: pass any value in adapter instance then read the value in adapter value to change text size , dont forget to refresh adapter again

Comment: Can you tell more about refresh Adapter? is that notifyDatasetChanged()?

Comment: it means call adapter again on menu change

Comment: Sry but do you mean setAdapter for recyclerView again?

Comment: yes i mean it, did you try it?or u want a solution?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried it and I can change the text size now but 1 more problem is if I refresh adapter then when i scroll down and press increase size button, then recyclerView will scroll to start. Do you have any idea to solve this?
Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: save instance of it and use it

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it now.

Comment: did it work for u?